# Confusing documentation re vectorized requests limits

Tags: support, documentation, tag-wiki

The [documentation for vectorized requests](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors) says this:

> Most methods that take ids in the Stack Exchange API will take up to **100** of them in a single go. This allows applications to batch work and thereby avoid unnecessary round trips, which can be a significant user experience win on slow or high latency devices.

So I was trying to pass up to 100 tags to the [`/tags/{tags}/wikis` API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags) but I kept getting a `Bad Request` error.

At first I thought it could be an undocumented difference between how limits for requests with vs without a key.

But then I found this in the tag wiki for that API:

> {tags} can contain up to **20** individual tags per request.

To prevent other people wasting time if they encounter this issue, shouldn't we clarify the vectorized requests documentation page to say that some APIs will have different limits and to consult their individual docs before assuming this "100"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well *technically* it already says "Most methods" so it's correct as written.

But I agree, it's easy to miss that note.  After the next build there will be another sentence mentioning that some methods have lower limits and their individual documentation pages will call them out (as they already do).  Should be harder to miss that way.